# How to change html input label name by custom angular directive in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-directive

I have multiple html forms where I should change or override  input label fields name with defined custom label names using api response. Can any one tell how should I do by defining custom directive?

E.g. Label name -> First Name  now I have to override that label name to some custom name -> Fst Name

Comment: Just curious, you can simply do it using interpolation. Why do you want make a custom directive ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```js
this.inputElement.nativeElement.value
```

to

```js
this.inputElement.nativeElement.innerText
```